# I cannot type in the Konqueror web-browser search bar

Tags: browser, konqueror

When I start up Ubuntu on my Toshiba Chromebook I try typing in the search bar of the internet browsing app "Konqueror" but nothing happens.

Comment: Has it ever worked?

Comment: No, it has not.

Comment: Perhaps the easiest solution is to install another browser...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer to your problems is probably to install a more developed and stable browser such as chromium...

## Installing Chromium in the terminal

As you cannot access a Web-browser, I suggest installing Chromium in the terminal... You can accomplish this by simply running the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install chromium-browser
```

Then simply launch Chromium and hopefully your issues are resolved, if not please leave a comment.